# XMLHttpRequest() returning response in a function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a function isOnline(), which looks like this:

```
function isOnline() {
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    request.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(request.readyState==4) {
            if(request.responseText=="online")
                return true;    
        }    
    }
    request.open("GET","onlinecheck.php?user=user",false);
    request.send();

    return false;
}
```

If I run `document.write(isOnline());` for testing , I ALWAYS get false, (undefined if i dont write `return false;` , I get undefined.

How do I 'wait' before the readyState is 4 and return true after that ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to focus on few things:

- `onreadystatechange` is used when sending an asynchronous request - [more here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp).
- So if you are trying to send an asynchronous request, use `async=true` in the call - read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

  ```
  request.open("GET", "onlinecheck.php?user=user", true);
  ```
- finally, if you are going to use asynchronous call, you can't return a value. Check these two links

  1. [Returning values from the event onreadystatechange in AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298112/returning-values-from-the-event-onreadystatechange-in-ajax)
  2. [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298112/returning-values-from-the-event-onreadystatechange-in-ajax)

---

In case you decide to do it synchronously:

```
function isOnline() {
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    request.open("GET","www.google.com/",false);
    request.send();

    /* check the readyState, you can also check for status code */
    if (request.readyState === 4)
        // put other conditions here if you need to    
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// It returns true
```