# Javascript ajax return wrong value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, return-value

> Issue : if i call ajax function i can't able to get return value.

Below is my simple javascript and ajax file.

**Javascript Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                return this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "testAjax.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    alert(loadDoc());
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World !!!";
?>
```

Can `synchronous` or `asynchronous` concept are useful to this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: check your browser console for `JS` error

Comment: I am not getting any error getting `undefined` in alert.

Comment: Per [PSR-2 2.2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#files), consider removing the ending `?>` if the file will contain only PHP.

Comment: You are returning value from onreadystatechange function which is not right, and your thinking about sync/async is correct, Use this link may be it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298112/returning-values-from-the-event-onreadystatechange-in-ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the asynchronous nature of ajax requests and the execution flow of code. The callback that is invoked when the conditions of `onreadystatechange` are met is not guaranteed to complete before the end of the main function has been reached. To achieve a return from the ajax function you need to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
let oPromise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            resolve( this.response );
        }
    };
    xhttp.open('GET', 'testAjax.php', true);
    xhttp.send();
});

oPromise.then( ( data ) => {
  alert('Whoohoo! -> ' + data );
});
```

To some  the syntax of the above will be unfamiliar and perhaps a little confusing - it could be rewritten in a more familar/tradional way like this:

```
let oPromise = new Promise( function( resolve,reject ){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload=function(){
        resolve( this.response )
    };
    xhr.onerror=function(){
        reject( this.readyState )
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'testAjax.php', true);
    xhr.send();
});
oPromise.then( function( response ){
     alert('Whoohoo! -> ' + response );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic like this:

```
function doJobWhenAjaxResultIsReturned(ajaxData){
    // alrt(ajaxData);
}
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      doJobWhenAjaxResultIsReturned(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "testAjax.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
loadDoc();
```

then do what you want in `doJobWhenAjaxResultIsReturned()`.