# get a boolean value of a function with xml http request for another function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

### Context

I have a form with three inputs (name, password, confirm password), that I want to validate with Javascript for certain criterias (e. g. minimum length of password, etc.). So I created the function *validateForm()* that does that.

One criteria is that the username shouldn't exist already. So I created the function *userExists()* (see below), that is called by *validateForm()*. *userExists()* works fine on its own, because it logs "Exists" or "Does not exist" correctly in the console.

### The Problem and Question

However I cannot get the value wether the userExists (true/false) from the *userExists()* function to the *validateForm()* function.

So my question is: **How do I get the info, if the User already exists from *userExists()* to *validateForm()*?**

I am new to Javascript and have been sitting on this issue for literrally a day now. I don't know how to solve this and would be really very grateful for some help.

### What I have tried so far

I added *return true;* and *return false;* beneath the *console.log("Exists / Does not exist")*, but when i then call *userExists()* in *validateForm()* I dont't get a true or false value (it is *"undefined"*).

I already tried a lot with solutions that refer to the function being asynchronos, (see [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)), like solving it with a boolean *variable* that saves the value, *Callbacks*, *timeout* and *await* (which it says in the editor I am not allowed to use in this case) and other suggestions , but that didn't solve it either.

```js
function validateForm() {

    //some code

    //get true/false of the function userExists() and give according alert (userExists() is undefined, doesn't work)
    else if(userExists()){
        alert("The name is already in use");
        name = "";
        return false;
    }

    //some code
}

function userExists() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 204) {
            //logs correctly in the console but doesn't return a boolean
                console.log("Exists");
                return true;
            } else if (xmlhttp.status == 404) {
                console.log("Does not exist");
                return false; 
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "#someLink", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `await` only works with `Promise`s (like the one returned from `fetch()`) and in an `async` context. The info _"Exists"_/_"Does not exist"_ is only available in the `onreadystatechange` event handler. Stop the submission of the form (e.g. `.preventDefault()`), and submit it in the _"Does not exist"_ case.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the info! I will try your suggestion

Comment: You cannot return value from ```onreadystatechange```. Instead use callback. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298112/returning-values-from-the-event-onreadystatechange-in-ajax

Comment: @AbhishekPandey thank you for this tip, I will try it right away ^^

Comment: Example (that will always end in the _"Does not exist"_ branch. Modify the URL for the other case): https://jsfiddle.net/8n109ogh/