# My function will log JSON data from an XMLHttpRequest but won't return it?

Tags: javascript, json, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to access the NHL API for a personal project. I was getting CORS request errors and found the below solution to access all the different sites (some worked prior, and some didn't).

I'm passing through a link and based one [the outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikBnj.png) it seems to be accessing the data on the page and displaying it in both JSON and string format. The only problem is I can't return any of that data out of the function as an object or otherwise.

Last 2 logs show undefined, and the 2 within the function output the data I want. Am I missing something obvious or is there a deeper issue with the website access?

Thanks.

```
function getJSON(url){
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    //Start writing function here
    console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    let data2 = JSON.stringify(data)
    return data2
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
request.send();
}

let data1 = getJSON("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8476459/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20212022")
console.log(data1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing asynchronous call, which means you return the value before the response even come back, that's why `data1` is `undefined`

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298112/returning-values-from-the-event-onreadystatechange-in-ajax) for more information.

For your case, you can wrap the request with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
async function getJSON(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.onload = function () {
      // Begin accessing JSON data here
      let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        //Start writing function here
       
        let data2 = JSON.stringify(data)
        return resolve(data);
      } else {
        return reject('error')
      }
    }
    request.send();
  }
  )
}

async function main() {
  let data1 = await getJSON("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8476459/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20212022")
console.log(data1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data1)); 
}

main();
```

A better way is to use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```js
async function getJSON(url) {
  const data1 = await fetch(url).
    then(response => response.json());
  return data1;
}
 
async function main() {
  const result = await getJSON('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8476459/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20212022');
  console.log(result);
}

main();
```